# '(@lvalue Int) -> $T7' is not identical to 'Dictionary<Int,Int>'

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm fairly new to programming, so be nice. I'm using the newest version of Xcode to build a tic-tac-toe game just for fun (single view application).

```
var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false

@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton){
    userMessage.hidden = true

    if !plays(sender.tag) && !aiDeciding && !done{
      setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
    }
```

At the conditional if statement (`if !plays(sender.tag)`), I'm getting an error that says:

> '(@lvalue Int) -> $T7' is not identical to 'Dictionary'

Comment: What does the second Int in your dictionary represent?  Your if statement is treating it as a  Boolean, but it isn't, it is an int. Also `plays(sender.tag)` will return an optional as there may not be a matching item in the dictionary for `sender.tag` so you will need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a handful of problems with your use of the `plays` dictionary.

The simplest is that you’re using `()` instead of `[]` for subscript access (i.e. `plays[sender.tag]`

Next, you can’t use the `!` on integers – unlike in some C-based languages, you can’t use integers as boolean values in Swift.  So you have to compare it to a specific value.  Presumably you’re checking that it’s equal to 0?

Finally, dictionaries return optional values in Swift, which you may need to unwrap.  But the good news is if all you care about it is whether it’s equal to 0, then you can compare it to a value without unwrapping it.

So this should work:

```
if plays[sender.tag] == 0 && !aiDeciding && !done {
    // etc…
}
```